# Why won't Java resolve this <generic> method signature?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I broke a build today with code I think should work:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class EmptyListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer,List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();

        map.put(Integer.valueOf(0), Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

The Eclipse Java compiler has no problem with this code, but Oracle's `javac` fails with this message:

```
src/java/EmptyListTest.java:9: error: no suitable method found for put(Integer,List<Object>)
map.put(Integer.valueOf(0), Collections.emptyList());
            ^
     method Map.put(Integer,List<String>) is not applicable
       (argument mismatch; List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>)
     method AbstractMap.put(Integer,List<String>) is not applicable
       (argument mismatch; List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>)
     method HashMap.put(Integer,List<String>) is not applicable
       (argument mismatch; List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>)
1 error
4 warnings
```

The obvious thing to do is to help-out the Oracle compiler by adding a cast to the `Collections.emptyList()`, but of course that causes its own compiler error (for both Eclipse *and* `javac`):

```
 /Users/chris/Documents/Eclipse/chadis-web/src/java/EmptyListTest.java:9: error: incompatible types: List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>
         map.put(Integer.valueOf(0), (List<String>)Collections.emptyList());
```

I'm well aware that Java's support for generics is officially terrible, but this seems like a common case that ought to work. I know I can just instantiate an empty list manually with the correct data type, but that's wasteful. I know I can split-up this line of code into two (one with a declaration of `List<String>` and assignment to `Collections.emptyList()` and another with the call to `Map<Integer,List<String>>.put()`, but that's just *more code* for no good reason.

Is there something else I can do to convince Oracle's `javac` that this code is valid?

Update: Using Eclipse Luna (not sure compiler version) and Oracle Java 1.8.0_151.

Update 2: looks like this was caused by the presence of `-source 1.5` as one of the arguments to the compiler. Using the default `source` for `javac` does not cause any errors. Strange that `Collections.emptyList()` behaves differently across versions when it hasn't changed since Java 1.5. There must have been some kind of change to the erasure-handling across versions that makes this work differently at different source-compatibility levels.

Comment: Did you try `Collections.<String>emptyList()` ?

Comment: Is your Eclipse on Java 9 while javac is Java 8?

Comment: oh i know that .. you write and test your code with eclipse but the maven build fails, cause he uses the oracle compiler ... :D

Comment: i compiled it with jdk 1.8.0-144 and it works ..

Comment: Works for me (Oracle `javac`) in both versions 8 and 9.  Are you using an ancient `javac`?

Comment: Updated question with version numbers. Not sure about what Eclipse does, but definitely using Java 8 CLI compiler.

Comment: Works for me on Java 8, you have something else wrong.

Comment: Tangential question: Do you understand `Collections.emptyList()` returns an immutable list? You can't add anything to it.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm intentionally using `Collections.emptyList` specifically because of that fact. I *have* written the odd Java program here and there.

Comment: *There must have been some kind of change to the erasure-handling across versions that makes this work differently at different source-compatibility levels.* It's not about erasure, but about type inference, which was [enhanced in Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101) to allow for exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

In some versions of Java (pre-Java 8, including Java 8 with a source-compatibility setting less than `1.8`) you need to specify the generic type so that `emptyList` will return a generic list rather than a raw one. You can do that by using:

```
Collections.<String>emptyList()
```

In more recent Java versions, the compiler can deduce the required generic type from the context, so you don't need to specify it. This deduction was [added in Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101) so that you don't have to specify the generic type at every step in the chain when using a stream.

Comment: Wow, what kind of witchcraft is *that*?

Comment: It's normal witchcraft. It is the normal way of specifying the generic type parameter for a method.

Comment: Just to mention, error comes only with Java version older than 8.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and reference.